# Get home feed of a particular user of a specific time stamp using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am trying to build a Facebook application by using Facebook Graph API. I am trying to get the home feed of the application user for a particular time span. e.g. From 11-02-2014 to 15-07-2014. I have used since and until in Facebook Graph Explorer but it returned news feed of two consecutive days.

Comment: I don't understand. Can we get more information about 1) the Graph API request you tried. 2) The result you get and what's wrong with it.

Comment: I have used /{user-id}/home this to get the home feed of a particular user. It returns content of one day. even if i used it with since and until like this

/{user-id}/home?since=2011-01-01&until=2011-05-05

but it returns posts of only 2 days maximum.

 But I want to get all the posts of a particular month or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2011-01-01` is the wrong synthax to represent a time on Facebook. You should use [Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): `1418971177`.

> #### A time-paginated edge supports the following parameters:
>
> - **until** : A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the    end of the range of time-based data.
> - **since** : A Unix timestamp or    strtotime data value that points to the start of the range of    time-based data.
> - **limit** : This is the number of individual objects    that are returned in each page. A limit of 0 will return no results.    Some
>     edges have an upper maximum on the limit value, for performance
>     reasons. We will return the correct pagination links if that happens.

*Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#*

---

So, instead of:

<strike>`/me/home?since=2011-01-01&until=2011-05-05`</strike>

You must use:

`/me/home?limit=25&until=1418971177` with `until`.

Or:

`/me/home?limit=25&since=1418971128` with `since`.

Note that you can't use `since` and `until` together. You have to use the `limit` field to restrict the amount of results you get.

Comment: You are right. But the problem is Facebook Changed their protocol. Now you can't get data for such a long time.